# data still saving on zero

Tags: vb.net

in my code the data is saving if no.of days to complete=0.I want it should not happen
in my code a msg comes "time to complete and time to acknowledged can be only be posiitve" but still data saves.i dont want it to be saved !!

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        Try
            Dim i As Integer
            If gvBanckmark.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i = 0 To gvBanckmark.Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim lblBenchMarkID As Label = CType(gvBanckmark.Rows(i).FindControl("lblBenchMarkID"), Label)
                    Dim lblSubCategoryId As Label = CType(gvBanckmark.Rows(i).FindControl("lblSubCategoryId"), Label)
                    Dim ddlFrequencyTypeAcknowledge As DropDownList = CType(gvBanckmark.Rows(i).FindControl("ddlFrequencyTypeAcknowledge"), DropDownList)
                    Dim ddlFrequencyTypeComplete As DropDownList = CType(gvBanckmark.Rows(i).FindControl("ddlFrequencyTypeComplete"), DropDownList)
                    Dim txtTimeToAcknowledge As TextBox = CType(gvBanckmark.Rows(i).FindControl("txtTimeToAcknowledge"), TextBox)
                    Dim txtTimeToComplete As TextBox = CType(gvBanckmark.Rows(i).FindControl("txtTimeToComplete"), TextBox)

                    Dim objBenchMark As BO.BenchMark = New BO.BenchMark()
                    objBenchMark.BuildingID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlBuilding.SelectedValue)
                    objBenchMark.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue)
                    objBenchMark.SubCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(lblSubCategoryId.Text.ToString())
                    objBenchMark.FrequencyTypeToAcknowledge = ddlFrequencyTypeAcknowledge.SelectedValue.ToString()
                    objBenchMark.FrequencyTypeToComplete = ddlFrequencyTypeComplete.SelectedValue.ToString()
                    objBenchMark.TimeToAcknowledge = Convert.ToInt32(txtTimeToAcknowledge.Text.ToString())
                    objBenchMark.TimeToComplete = Convert.ToInt32(txtTimeToComplete.Text.ToString())

                    If lblBenchMarkID.Text.ToString() = 0 Then
                        objBenchMark.BenchMarkID = 0
                        objBenchMark.CreateByUserId = UserWrapper.GetCurrentUser().ContactID
                        BO.BenchMark.InsertBechMarkData(objBenchMark)
                    Else
                        objBenchMark.BenchMarkID = Convert.ToInt32(lblBenchMarkID.Text.ToString())
                        objBenchMark.ModifiedByUserId = UserWrapper.GetCurrentUser().ContactID
                        BO.BenchMark.UpdateBechMarkData(objBenchMark)
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
            lblError.Visible = True
            lblError.Text = "<a cssClass=""messageGood"">Benchmark data has been saved sucessfully.</a>"
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblError.Text = ex.Message
            lblError.Visible = True
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not being saved, but the message telling you the data has been saved is being presented, despite it's saved or not.

Move thses lines inside the if-end if:

```
lblError.Visible = True
lblError.Text = "<a cssClass=""messageGood"">Benchmark data has been saved sucessfully.</a>"
```

Comment: ALso, there's no code showing the message you told on the description, add the real code.